# idea how to know one jar comes from where

Tags: intellij-idea

idea 2020 ultimate.

i have multiple projects, they look like:

[image]

wherein `projectA` and `projectB` are independent web app. i import them to idea.

i have two questions:

1. all jars are shown under the `External Libraries` rather than `projectA`, `projectB` etc, is it right?
2. if #1 is right, now how can i know `aopalliance` is from where(i don't add it explicitly)?

   i understand that if it is from `projectA`, i can select `projectA` then choose `show dependencies`, but now i don't know it is in `projectA` or `projectB` or else.

Comment: You may expand library node, select "aopalliance.jar", right-click, select "Open Library Settings" and then right-click and select "Find Usages".

Comment: You can try to use `mvn dependency:tree` to show all dependencies with transient ones
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Comment: @y.bedrov thanks, it works. could u post it as an answer such that i can accept it?

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov where to run `mvn dependency:tree`? because i don't know this dependency is from which project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may expand library node, select "aopalliance.jar", right-click, select "Open Library Settings" and then right-click and select "Find Usages".